# Flipping Book PHP Code? Any experience?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, hooks

Hi there guys quick question, using FlippingBook and calling a gallery within a page or post is with something like this: `[book id='1' /]` but I want to call the gallery directly from my code, so is there any php code to achieve this? Thanks guys!

Arturo

http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-flip-image-gallery/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer but I think it is all you need.

`do_shortcode("[book id='1' /]");`

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Don't forget to escape your single quote character or use double-quotes.